# How can I get the PI Label "Highlights" (or page 1) of the drug's label

Tags: api, openfda

Are the "highlight of the prescribing label" available through openFDA?

Answer (score 0):

The openFDA drug label API does not provide the "Highlights" as a separate or discrete item. The ordering of the data fields in the openFDA API results can and will vary. So, there is no "page 1" per se.  The "Highlights" when available will be included as part of the drug label record.

For example,

"Highlights" PDF for Lyrica:
https://www.accessdata.fda.gov/drugsatfda_docs/label/2011/021446s026,022488s005lbl.pdf

Record in openFDA's Drug Label API for Lyrica:
https://api.fda.gov/drug/label.json?search=brand_name:lyrica